# Добавление кнопок определенное число раз после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: menu, qt, c++

Всем привет.

Есть на форме меню с вкладкой "Добавить кнопку".
Кликаю по нему, добавляется кнопка  pushbutton в определенной позиции.
Еще раз кликаю  по нему, добавляется кнопка и так до 5 раз. Если 5 раз кликнули то вкладка "Добавить кнопку" становится недоступной.

Как можно сделать при нажатии на одну и ту же меню вкладки добавлялись кнопки 5 раз?

Можно ли справа от вкладки "Добавить кнопку" был счетчик, с начальным значением 5, потом каждый раз при нажатии она уменьшилась на 1?

В листинге описывается форма с меню. На форме есть кнопка, с начальным значением setvisible(false). После нажатия на меню "Добавить кнопку" кнопка принимает значение setvisible(true).

```
//mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    void createActions();
private slots:
     void addButtons();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

//mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    createActions();
    ui->pushButton->setVisible(false);
    //ui->pushButton->setGeometry(100,100,100,100);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::createActions()
{
    connect(ui->addAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(addButtons()));
}
void MainWindow::addButtons()
{
    ui->pushButton->setVisible(true);
}

//main.cpp
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Или такая идея есть 5 кнопок, первоначальные значения setvisible(false). А потом по мере необходимости ставить setvisible(true).

Answer (score 2):

```
int a = 4; // Объявить при загрузке формы
При клике на кнопку: {
    if (a > 0) {
        Добавить кнопку;
        a = a - 1;
    }
    else ничего;
}
```